# Map multiple indexed routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a number of controllers in application:

```
ApiV1Controller
ApiV2Controller
ApiV3Controller
...
```

Is it possible to map routes for them with single `MapRoute` statement to URLs like `/api/v1/{action}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom route. Let's suppose that you have the following controllers:

```
public class ApiV1Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("v1");
    }
}

public class ApiV2Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("v2");
    }
}

public class ApiV3Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("v3");
    }
}
```

Now write a custom route:

```
public class ApiRoute : Route
{
    public ApiRoute()
        : base("api/{version}/{action}", new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "index" }), new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        rd.Values["controller"] = "Api" + rd.GetRequiredString("version");
        return rd;
    }
}
```

That could be registered in your `Global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add("ApiRoute", new ApiRoute());

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

and that's pretty much it. Now you could play with urls:

- `/api/v1`
- `/api/v2`
- `/api/v3`